# How can I delete my account...?

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

Recent events have made it clear to me that after giving up attempts to create a friendly environment years ago, Stack Exchange now prioritises [identity politics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_politics) over everything else. This is not an environment to which I wish to contribute.

Unfortunately, the instructions for deleting accounts appear to be out of date. They say there is a link "Edit Profile & Settings" on the "profile page" or on the "user page". Presumably that would be the page that I can reach by clicking on 'my' icon when logged in. There is no such link there, nor anything similar, and I can't find anything better.

So how can one delete one's profile nowadays?

Comment: Try https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/622783

Comment: @Snow: Thanks a lot. That actually solved the problem.

Comment: No worries.  Glad to help.

Comment: Would you happen to also know how one can delete all profiles? If I have to do it separately for all 'sites' of this company that I have used in the past, then I will go the easier route and ask them to do this by email. As they are clearly targeting an EU audience, too, they MUST offer an option to delete everything.

Comment: @HansAdler yeah, you have to visit each site. There is NO overall *nuke all* button. Technically visiting each site and click delete is the option they offer to delete everything.There is no GDPR ruling that states that deleting needs to be *easy*.

Comment: No GDPR ruling yet, sure. But this is clearly analogous to things that have been decided before. E.g., a company cannot let consumers enter into contracts via telephone or email but insist on a letter or fax for canceling.

Comment: SE is in a bit of an odd situation, having so many accounts for the same person. Most companies simply don't have to deal with 120 account deletions from the same user on the same day.

Comment: Were you perhaps using the mobile web version of the site? The Edit Profile link does not appear on your profile there, as the page isn't mobile-optimized. You'd need to request the desktop version to see it.

Comment: HansAdler: In my opinion, your action constitutes grandstanding, and only serves to exacerbating the problem you bemoan. If, in your daily use of the network, you experience "prioritization of identity politics over everything else" - then by all means leave. Otherwise, I suggest you take a long breath and remember that German.SE , English.SE and other sites you're on are still good curated collections of questions and answers that are worth contributing to.

Comment: @Animuson: No, I never use smartphones. I was unable to find my profile page normally in Google Chromium on Linux. Today I am using Google Chrome on Windows, and I can reach it normally by clicking to top right icon. Obviously I have my suspicions concerning the timing of this bug, which may be unfair.

Comment: @einpoklum: This may be grandstanding, but it is a political reaction to the political problem of politicising things that should not be political. Stack Exchange has become a seriously unfriendly environment over the years with hyperactive moderators policing the community in ways that are simply not acceptable. (Deleting valid questions as duplicates when they are not. And recently I got an answer deleted for pointing out the current conflict between academia and publishers in a context where it was relevant.)

Comment: @einpoklum: Currently there is a political shift to the right everywhere, hidden behind a combative ideology of overemphasising certain minorities (while completely ignoring others). In this climate, making a site more friendly apparently means 'making it more diverse'. Which in practice has the opposite effect for almost everyone who is not a right-wing warrior claiming to be fighting for the minorities du jour. I want nothing to do with a site that is so strongly affected by this problem.